# Navigation from jquery UI widget's instance back to widget

Tags: jquery-ui

Is it possible to navigate from a jquery UI widget's instance back to the widget? In this case, retrieving the value stored in `$table` from `resultTable`?

```
    var $div = $("<div/>");
    var $table = $div.resultTable(resultTableSettings);
    var resultTable = $table.resultTable("instance");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `resultTable.element`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22334506)

Comment: It provides the exact answer to the question.